# "Reroute" traffic using a Debian VPN server

Tags: linux, debian, vpn

I've set up a Debian VPN server, to which I connect with my iPhone. It works perfectly, I can browse the web, and see "local" pages.

My question is, if it's possible to "reroute" traffic. Here's an example:

**On the iPhone, I go to "www.wiki.jeff" or something, and it reroutes me to "192.168.1.10/wiki/index.php"**

That's the general idea I have. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Are you running a local DNS server such as PowerDNS or BIND? Which one?

Comment: Yes.  Easily doable?  Not so much.  It would require you running a DNS server, and then setting that as the iPhone's DNS server.  Then You would have to have a web server to redirect.

Comment: @sarnold: I use the standard DNS. I haven't set up any DNS server manually.

Comment: @Corbin: thanks! So no method which only needs you to connect to the VPN and everything on the iPhone/PC side will be automatically configured?

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans Not unless you're willing to hijack some packets (which will be difficult, and a bit shady).

Comment: @Corbin I see. Thanks anyways, it would've been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this specifically with an iPhone, but the principle isn't too hard in general:

- Set up a DNS server

  - It needs to be advertised as the DNS server to the iPhone via DHCP
  - It needs to by an authoritative server for the zone `.jeff.` and answer responses for `wiki.jeff.`
  - It needs to be able to run recursive queries itself or forward queries to another server if it is not itself a recursive server.
- Set your DHCP server to hand out the IP of your DNS server
- Set your webserver to also respond to the name `wiki.jeff` and select the correct content.

This sounds like a lot, but the pieces are all pretty small and manageable.

The [`pdns-recursor` package installs the PowerDNS recursor](http://doc.powerdns.com/built-in-recursor.html) which can be configured (`export-etc-hosts=yes`) to *also* serve up the contents of the `/etc/hosts` file -- or any other file following that same format (`etc-hosts-file`) on incoming requests. `pdns-recursor` is fantastically flexible and *fast* -- it can be used to paper over weak or flaky ISP-provided DNS systems and this cheapo method of serving a handful of new hostname mappings is *really* easy. (The full-blown [PowerDNS server](http://doc.powerdns.com/) is something awesome to behold but is *extremely* overkill for this case.)

When adding a new line to your `/etc/hosts` file, recall that `127.0.0.1` means `localhost` to *every* peer -- not *this server*. Give `wiki.jeff` an IP address that your iPhone can route.

You'll have to figure out how to modify your DHCP server to send out a specific IP address for DNS queries. This varies from server to server, but the option is known as `option domain-name-servers` in the ISC DHCP server. Add the IP of your newly configured `pdns-recursor` system. (Which could be a different machine than the IP address you're serving for `wiki.jeff`.)

You'll have to modify your webserver to also handle the `wiki.jeff` name; under [`nginx` this is directive `server_name`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name). Apache needs [`ServerName` or `ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) directives.